# VB6 Crash Dump Symbol is not being resolved

Tags: vb6, crash, windbg, crash-dumps

I am unable to figure this problem out. Symbol is not being resolved

**Deployment**

There are number of exes of my system deployed on a network path. All users run those exes from that shared network path. This was working fine two weeks ago but now some of those exes have started crashing. There is no fix pattern of being crashed, it happens to any user, anytime during any activity.

**Troubleshooting**

I have got the dump of one of them, i tried WinDbg and got following

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.16384 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\crash\RNS1000.exe.mdmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\crash*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\crash
Executable search path is: 
Windows XP Version 2600 (Service Pack 3) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Wed Oct 10 15:36:36.000 2012 (UTC + 5:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 7:12:54.000
................................................................
.........................................................
Loading unloaded module list
.......
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(924.85c): In-page I/O error ffffffffc000020c - code c0000006 (first/second chance not available)
eax=02060000 ebx=7c90fe01 ecx=00001000 edx=7c90e4f4 esi=000003a0 edi=00000000
eip=7c90e4f4 esp=0013afdc ebp=0013b040 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00200297
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
7c90e4f4 c3              ret
0:000> !analyze -v 
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12007.

FAULTING_IP: 
RNS1000+55f610
0095f610 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0095f610 (RNS1000+0x0055f610)
   ExceptionCode: c0000006 (In-page I/O error)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: 00000008
   Parameter[1]: 0095f610
   Parameter[2]: c000020c
Inpage operation failed at 0095f610, due to I/O error c000020c

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  RNS1000.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000006 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O error status of "0x%08lx".

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000006 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O error status of "0x%08lx".

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000008

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0095f610

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  c000020c

IO_ERROR: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000020c - The transport connection is now disconnected.

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000 to 00000000

APP:  rns1000.exe

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000 00000000 hardware_disk!Unknown+0x0


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  hardware_disk!Unknown

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: hardware_disk

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_c0000006_hardware_disk!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_hardware_disk!Unknown

IMAGE_NAME:  hardware_disk

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/RNS1000_exe/2_0_0_5/4f17b9d2/RNS1000_exe/2_0_0_5/4f17b9d2/c0000006/0055f610.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

I am expecting **RNS1000+55f610** to be resolved to one of my programs function but it has not been resolved. The sysmbol path contains exe, pdb and mdmp.

Please tell me why has it not been resolved? what wrong am i doing?

Comment: @Deanna, I had got symbols resolved on another pc, i might have some configuration issue on my pc, i didn't go into details. Though you were helpful that it is windows subsystem which is crashing and i can't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

The key part here is the `In-page I/O error`. The underlying disk/network drive disappeared.
The crash occurs some time later when it tries to page back in part of the executable, but it no longer has a valid file handle/connection.

The only fix is to run it locally or make sure the disk doesn't disappear while they're running.

More generally, you can get VB to create the info files for native debugging using the "Create symbolic debug info" option in the project's Compile settings. This can only be done before the fact though and won't help with debugging an existing build.

Comment: Yes, i am planning to deploy it locally for some of the users. But, i also want to know which of the function is crashing, whether while accessing database so something else

Comment: @bjan: It could be absolutely anywhere, there is no way you can handle or fix this situation in the executable. It's got to a point where it can't run part of the executable and the only option is to crash and shut down.

Comment: I agree with you on "the only option is to crash and shut down", but i have seen such applications which handle network failure very nicely so i wonder if it could be handled because it is very bad for our customer relationship for something which is at least their own mistake/failure.

Comment: @bjan It depends on what the failure is and on the context. If your application is trying to access something and that failed, fine, handle it, retry whatever. In this case, it's the windows subsystem that is crashing accessing your executable. Your code isn't even coming into play in the crash because it can not load it.